# Matching fields in two text files from separate columns, then appending one files contents where matches were found, including duplicates

Tags: bash, awk

I've been searching through a lot of similar questions, but many are matching columns a bit differently and I haven't been able to adapt the awk commands people are sharing to work as I need.

Simply put I have 2 files, 1 with a list of basically names and duties. The second file has entries of items prepended by the same names listed in file 1, *but* there can be duplicate entries under a name in file 2.

Here's what some example data close to what I'm working with looks like

File 1

```
Priest - IhaveaName 
Priest - Larry Boy 
Priest - Jeff 
Melee - Jorge 
Stealth - Wontseeme 
Shaman - Chester 
Caster - Clyde 
Stealth - ImNamedtoo 
Melee - Don 
Stealth - Lester  
Healer - Larry 
Caster - Beans  
Stealth - Enwef  
Melee - Doug 
Stealth - Bossman 
Totems - Sub
Healer - Rammmma
```

File 2

```
Larry Boy - Boots 
Larry Boy - Midnight Haze 
Larry Boy - Plague Bearer
Jorge - Buckler 
Chester - Handguards
Clyde - Cloak
Don - Stone Pendant 
Don - Rolled
Lester - Stone
Beans - Stopwatch
Rammmma - Splinter collector 
Rammmma - Splinter collector
```

Expected results

```
Priest - Larry Boy - Boots 
Priest - Larry Boy - Midnight Haze 
Priest - Larry Boy - Plague Bearer
Melee - Jorge - Buckler 
Shaman - Chester - Handguards
Caster - Clyde - Cloak
Melee - Don - Stone Pendant 
Melee - Don - Rolled
Stealth - Lester - Headpiece
Caster - Beans - Stopwatch
Healer - Rammmma - Splinter collector 
Healer - Rammmma - Splinter collector
```

As you can see in the expected results, the names in File 1 are matched with the names in File 2, but there is a difference in line counts and entry amounts will always vary. What ideally happens next is that File 2 is prefixed on every matching line with the line from File 1 that matched (preferably without the could be duplicated name), thus giving the expected results above.

The closest I have gotten is with awk using this command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} ($2 in a) {print a[$2]" -",$0}' member_classes_rearranged.txt 2021_Mar_02_Naxx_alphabetical.txt
```

But it's output shows the same class for every line instead of matching any.

Not sure if it was that version of another, but I was also running into issues with awk not processing the whole file. It was finding the first entry in file 2, then ignoring if the next 2-3+ had the same name, even if what followed the name differed.

Really appreciate any help. Hopefully I explained this thoroughly!

Comment: This can be solved by familiarizing yourself with awk more. Or by someone handing out an answer.

Comment: Default field delimiter is space, using in this form you can only partially match the multi word names.  However `$2` refers to hyphen not the values you think you're referring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F' - ' 'NR==FNR {sub(" +$","",$2); a[$2]=$1; next} 
               $1 in a {print a[$1] FS $0}' file1 file2

Priest - Larry Boy - Boots
Priest - Larry Boy - Midnight Haze
Priest - Larry Boy - Plague Bearer
Melee - Jorge - Buckler
Shaman - Chester - Handguards
Caster - Clyde - Cloak
Melee - Don - Stone Pendant
Melee - Don - Rolled
Caster - Beans - Stopwatch
Healer - Rammmma - Splinter collector
Healer - Rammmma - Splinter collector
```

Three issues I noticed are:

1. you have empty space end of lines, requires trimming;
2. `Stealth - Lester` line in file2 is transposed, so it's not going to match;
3. `Healer` became `Heals` in expected output, which doesn't happen by
   itself unless you modify it.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I wanted!

And yes, what you noticed are just mistakes I made in creating the example data sets.

Comment: I ran into an interesting situation I hadn't thought to include in the initial question. On some lines comments can be included in parenthesis after the name, like this 
`Larry Boy (passed by name) - Midnight Haze`  
which causes the awk command to exclude those lines. Moving them to the end of the line instead makes it work as expected. 
Their position doesn't matter much vs the other fields, so moving them before with sed like I'm trying now is fine, but I'm still curious if awk could handle those lines at the same time?  Really appreciate the help.